# C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: linux-mint, gcc, wine

I'm trying to install wine on Linux Mint 17.1. I ./configure'd as root to install it.

Input:

```
cd Downloads/wine-1.6.2
./configure
```

Output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/(my username)/Downloads/wine-1.6.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log:
        This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
        running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

```
    It was created by Wine configure 1.6.2, which was
    generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

      $ ./configure 

    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##

    hostname = Math2
    uname -m = x86_64
    uname -r = 3.13.0-37-generic
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014

    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown

    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown

    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/games
    PATH: /usr/local/games


    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:2879: checking build system type
    configure:2893: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    configure:2913: checking host system type
    configure:2926: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    configure:2956: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
    configure:2978: result: yes
    configure:3035: checking for gcc
    configure:3051: found /usr/bin/gcc
    configure:3062: result: gcc
    configure:3291: checking for C compiler version
    configure:3300: gcc --version >&5
    gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
    configure:3311: $? = 0
    configure:3300: gcc -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
    configure:3311: $? = 0
    configure:3300: gcc -V >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3311: $? = 4
    configure:3300: gcc -qversion >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3311: $? = 4
    configure:3331: checking whether the C compiler works
    configure:3353: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:3357: $? = 1
    configure:3395: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "Wine"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "wine"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.6.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "Wine 1.6.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "wine-devel@winehq.org"
    | #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.winehq.org"
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | 
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:3400: error: in `/home/(my username)/Desktop/Other_Games/wine-1.6.2':
    configure:3402: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details

    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##

    ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
    ac_cv_env_DBUS_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_DBUS_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_DBUS_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_DBUS_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_FREETYPE_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_FREETYPE_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_FREETYPE_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_FREETYPE_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GNUTLS_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GNUTLS_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_PORT_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_PORT_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_PORT_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GPHOTO2_PORT_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GSTREAMER_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GSTREAMER_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_GSTREAMER_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_GSTREAMER_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_HAL_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_HAL_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_HAL_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_HAL_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LCMS2_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LCMS2_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LCMS2_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LCMS2_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_PNG_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_PNG_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_PNG_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_PNG_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_SANE_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_SANE_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_SANE_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_SANE_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_XMKMF_set=
    ac_cv_env_XMKMF_value=
    ac_cv_env_XML2_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_XML2_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_XML2_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_XML2_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_XSLT_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_XSLT_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_XSLT_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_XSLT_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
    ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
    ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

    ## ----------------- ##
    ## Output variables. ##
    ## ----------------- ##

    ALL_TEST_RESOURCES=''
    ALSALIBS=''
    APPKITLIB=''
    APPLICATIONSERVICESLIB=''
    AR=''
    ARFLAGS=''
    BISON=''
    BUILTINFLAG=''
    CARBONLIB=''
    CC='gcc'
    CFLAGS=''
    CONVERT=''
    COREAUDIO=''
    COREFOUNDATIONLIB=''
    CORESERVICESLIB=''
    CPP=''
    CPPBIN=''
    CPPFLAGS=''
    CROSSCC=''
    CROSSTARGET=''
    CROSSTEST_DISABLE=''
    CUPSINCL=''
    CXX=''
    CXXFLAGS=''
    DBUS_CFLAGS=''
    DBUS_LIBS=''
    DEFS=''
    DISKARBITRATIONLIB=''
    DLLEXT=''
    DLLFLAGS=''
    DLLTOOL=''
    ECHO_C=''
    ECHO_N='-n'
    ECHO_T=''
    EGREP=''
    EXEEXT=''
    EXTRACFLAGS=''
    EXTRA_BINARIES=''
    FLEX=''
    FONTCONFIGINCL=''
    FONTFORGE=''
    FORCEFEEDBACKLIB=''
    FRAMEWORK_OPENAL=''
    FREETYPE_CFLAGS=''
    FREETYPE_LIBS=''
    GNUTLS_CFLAGS=''
    GNUTLS_LIBS=''
    GPHOTO2_CFLAGS=''
    GPHOTO2_LIBS=''
    GPHOTO2_PORT_CFLAGS=''
    GPHOTO2_PORT_LIBS=''
    GREP=''
    GSTREAMER_CFLAGS=''
    GSTREAMER_LIBS=''
    HAL_CFLAGS=''
    HAL_LIBS=''
    ICOTOOL=''
    IMPLIBEXT=''
    INSTALL_DATA=''
    INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
    INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
    IOKITLIB=''
    LCMS2_CFLAGS=''
    LCMS2_LIBS=''
    LDAPLIBS=''
    LDCONFIG=''
    LDD=''
    LDDLLFLAGS=''
    LDEXECFLAGS=''
    LDFLAGS=''
    LDPATH=''
    LDRPATH_INSTALL=''
    LDRPATH_LOCAL=''
    LIBDL=''
    LIBGETTEXTPO=''
    LIBKSTAT=''
    LIBMPG123=''
    LIBOBJS=''
    LIBOPENAL=''
    LIBOPENCL=''
    LIBPOLL=''
    LIBPTHREAD=''
    LIBRT=''
    LIBS=''
    LIBWINE_RULES=''
    LINGUAS=''
    LINT=''
    LINTFLAGS=''
    LN_S=''
    LTLIBOBJS=''
    MAINTAINER_MODE=''
    MAIN_BINARY=''
    MSGFMT=''
    OBJEXT=''
    OPENGL_LIBS=''
    OSS4INCL=''
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='wine-devel@winehq.org'
    PACKAGE_NAME='Wine'
    PACKAGE_STRING='Wine 1.6.2'
    PACKAGE_TARNAME='wine'
    PACKAGE_URL='http://www.winehq.org'
    PACKAGE_VERSION='1.6.2'
    PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
    PKG_CONFIG=''
    PNG_CFLAGS=''
    PNG_LIBS=''
    PORCFLAGS=''
    PRELINK=''
    QUICKTIMELIB=''
    RANLIB=''
    READELF=''
    RESOLVLIBS=''
    RSVG=''
    SANE_CFLAGS=''
    SANE_LIBS=''
    SECURITYLIB=''
    SET_MAKE=''
    SHELL='/bin/bash'
    SOCKETLIBS=''
    TARGETFLAGS=''
    TOOLSDIR=''
    TOOLSEXT=''
    UNWINDFLAGS=''
    WOW64_DISABLE=''
    XLIB=''
    XMKMF=''
    XML2_CFLAGS=''
    XML2_LIBS=''
    XSLT_CFLAGS=''
    XSLT_LIBS=''
    X_CFLAGS=''
    X_EXTRA_LIBS=''
    X_LIBS=''
    X_PRE_LIBS=''
    ZLIB=''
    ac_ct_AR=''
    ac_ct_CC='gcc'
    ac_ct_CXX=''
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
    build_alias=''
    build_cpu='x86_64'
    build_os='linux-gnu'
    build_vendor='unknown'
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    exec_prefix='NONE'
    host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
    host_alias=''
    host_cpu='x86_64'
    host_os='linux-gnu'
    host_vendor='unknown'
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    prefix='NONE'
    program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
    psdir='${docdir}'
    sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
    sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
    sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
    target_alias=''

    ## ------------------- ##
    ## File substitutions. ##
    ## ------------------- ##

    MAKE_DLL_RULES=''
    MAKE_IMPLIB_RULES=''
    MAKE_PROG_RULES=''
    MAKE_RULES=''
    MAKE_TEST_RULES=''

    ## ----------- ##
    ## confdefs.h. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    /* confdefs.h */
    #define PACKAGE_NAME "Wine"
    #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "wine"
    #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.6.2"
    #define PACKAGE_STRING "Wine 1.6.2"
    #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "wine-devel@winehq.org"
    #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.winehq.org"

    configure: exit 77

    (END)
```

I've lurked through here and other places around the internet to find an answer with no luck, so here I am.

Comment: What happens if you create a trivial C program `foo.c` and say `gcc foo.c`?  If that fails, that's your problem, and you should focus your question on that (and never mind the fact that you're trying to install wine).  If the `gcc` succeeds, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Compiling stuff onself is sooo rewarding... Especially when it becomes group-compiling because the OP has not a clue of what he is doing (having one, would require actual reding and understanding)... But well, there are always people available to answer questions. It's a shame though when the question is actually not the real problem...

Answer (score 18):

Don't worry about these errors:

```
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
```

and

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
```

Those are unsuccessful probes but the `configure` script perseveres after them.

Do worry about these:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
```

Those files are part of the `libc6-dev` package and are required in order to built any type of normal executable. You are probably missing that package. Try installing it (or reinstalling it if it is already installed — perhaps it is broken).

Better yet, install the `build-essential` package. That's a meta-package that will pull in all of the bare essentials for compiling things.

Comment: `build-essential` is the right way to go

Comment: @eyoung100 the question *is* why is compiling the source failing. The answer can't be 'don't do that, use the binary'. Maybe he wants to set different build options. Maybe he wants to patch the source. Maybe he just wants to learn how to build it.

Comment: 1 up for build-essential

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, do not build it as root.  Generally you will need root privilege with `sudo` only at the final step you install it in the system.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

According to `config.log`, you failed to build executables because libc and other libraries are missing on your system.  On Debian based systems you can install essential tools and libraries by running:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

In addition to that, you need various dependencies and complicated set up regarding Win32/Win64 to build Wine for yourself, which would be rather hard way.  Read developer's documents carefully [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/Recommended_Packages) and [there](http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit).  You can find the recommended way for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You could have unrecognized CFLAGS set.

Try using

```
export CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
```

before you run ./configure

Answer (score -1):

After some googling...

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```